# Search Engine Bug PHP&Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search

Hi Guys I've got a problem in my search engine. Here's the code:

```
$types = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']);

//Convertion de GET
if ($types = "air") {
    $searchq = "LF";
}elseif ($types = "huile") {
    $searchq = "OF";
}elseif ($types = "carburant") {
    $searchq = "KF";
}elseif ($types = "habitacle") {
    $searchq = "CF";
}elseif ($types = "eau") {
    $searchq = "WF";
}else{
    $searchq = "DF";
}


$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%'") 
    or die("La Recherche est impossible");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tProduct WHERE sSearch LIKE '%$searchq%'");
```

But the problem is that `searchq` takes only the value of `LF`.

Where is the problem in my code please?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: but to switch to PDO or mysqli I have to change all the codes of all my script

Comment: I know, but you'll thank me later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($types == "air") {
    $searchq = "LF";
}elseif ($types == "huile") {
    $searchq = "OF";
}elseif ($types == "carburant") {
    $searchq = "KF";
}elseif ($types == "habitacle") {
    $searchq = "CF";
}elseif ($types == "eau") {
    $searchq = "WF";
}else{
    $searchq = "DF";
}
```

You are assigning instead of comparing.
Use `==` to compare strings

See documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

A side note, you should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements. mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: but to switch to PDO or mysqli I have to change all the codes of all my script

Comment: The way that I think about it is, you can do it now, before you add any more code, and while you are not in a time crunch, or you can wait for the day when you have double the codebase and you are in an emergency situation where you have to update your application in a very short amount of time.

Comment: Yeah, mysqli might be the easiest transition. Switching the code is just going to spare you a future headache. While it is not likely mysql_ functions will just stop working, at least not any time soon, they are officially deprecated. You can bet for a good reason.